# How can I store/setStates of several inputs from a mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am working on a project, where a user would provide questions and at the time of applying, the applicant would provide responses to these questions.

Here is my array of the user's questions

```
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({})
    questions = [
        {id: 1, questionType: boolean, required: true, question: 'Are you a UK resident?'}, 
        {id: 2, questionType: text, required: true, question: 'give brief description about you'}, 
        {id: 3, questionType: text, required: false, question: 'How old are you'}
     ]
```

from this array, I've mapped each of them

```
{questions?.map((q) => (
        <Box sx={{ py: 1 }} key={q.id}>
          <p>{q.question}</p>
          {q?.questionType === 'boolean' ? (
            <Select
              id='location'
              required={q.required}
              onChange={(e) => setAnswers(e.target.value)}
            >
              <MenuItem value='Yes'>Yes</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value='No'>No</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          ) : (
            <OutlinedInput
              required
              id='name'
              type='text'
              onChange={(e) => setAnswers(e.target.value)}
            />
          )}
```

The answer of the first one overrides the answer of the second one. How do i fix this?? SO i can persist all the answers.

Comment: Provide `key` in items of map. `questions?.map((q,index) => (<Box key={index}` ...

Comment: yea, but how do i store each response in state?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use a Map which maps question IDs to answers to keep track of questions and the associated answers.

```js
// map that stores an answer to a question ID
// e.g. 
// 1 => Yes
// 2 => I am a developer
// 3 => 123
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState(new Map());
questions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    questionType: boolean,
    required: true,
    question: "Are you a UK resident?",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    questionType: text,
    required: true,
    question: "give brief description about you",
  },
  { id: 3, questionType: text, required: false, question: "How old are you" },
];
```

Then have a function which updates the Map whenever a question is answered. This function takes the question ID and the value. It also has to create a new Map every time as React only does a shallow comparison and state should be treated as immutable.

```js
function updateAnswer(id, value) {
  const newMap = new Map(answers);
  newMap.set(id, value);
  setAnswers(newMap);
}
```

Then last but not least you need to call your update function.

```js
{questions?.map((q) => (
  <Box sx={{ py: 1 }} key={q.id}>
    <p>{q.question}</p>
    {q?.questionType === 'boolean' ? (
      <Select
        id='location'
        required={q.required}
        onChange={(e) => updateAnswer(q.id, e.target.value)}
      >
        <MenuItem value='Yes'>Yes</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='No'>No</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    ) : (
      <OutlinedInput
        required
        id='name'
        type='text'
        onChange={(e) => updateAnswer(q.id, e.target.value)}
      />
    )}
```